# Rails: BCrypt::Errors::InvalidHash (invalid hash) Devise 1.5.4 Rails 2.2.5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

we are using the following in devise.rb

```
config.encryptor = :bcrypt
```

We wanted to change this to

```
config.encryptor = :authlogic_sha512
```

Also written code to decrypt old password and hash it to new one when signing in (inside session controller)

However, after updating the password, on signing out and signing in, it gives an error

```
BCrypt::Errors::InvalidHash (invalid hash):
```

This error comes at random places if I comment out the original point of the error. So I suppose there is something wrong with either the devise configuration OR with the user.rb model.

The user model has the following line:

```
devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :confirmable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :omniauthable, :omniauth_providers => [:auth0, :google_oauth2]
```

So the sequence of steps is this:

1. User's info is there in the DB (existing user). Password encrypted with bcrypt
2. User signs-in and in sessions controller, we re-hash the password to sha512 and store it in encrypted_password field
3. User signs-out
4. User signs-in *** Unable to sign in due to 'invalid_hash' error.

Any idea what could be the issue here? thanks in advance.

**Edit: Code for Step 2 above as requested:**

```
class Users::SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
...
...
email = params[:user]['login']

@user = User.find_by_email(email)
return if @user.nil?
# Get old password and salt
bcrypt = BCrypt::Password.new(@user.encrypted_password)
salt = bcrypt.salt

pwd = params[:user]['password']

pass = ::BCrypt::Engine.hash_secret("#{pwd}#{Devise.pepper}", salt)
# If passwords, match, re-hash it with SHA-512
if @user.encrypted_password == pass
  @user.password_digest = ::Devise::Encryptors::AuthlogicSha512.digest(pass, Devise.stretches, salt, Devise.pepper)
  @user.password_salt = salt
  @user.save!
end
```

I also added 'password_digest' and 'password_salt' in the db table but my 'save!' method then fails with 'extra arguments not passed'.

Comment: The actual source code for #2 might be helpful since that is probably where the problem lies. I assume you're overriding Devise's `SessionController`? How?

Comment: @ma_il added code as requested.

Comment: did you find the solution of this problem ??

Comment: @abby37 Nope, didn't find a solution to this.

Comment: u r getting encrypted_password, then why u still need password_digest??

Answer (score 11):

I had a similar issue when setting up a **Rails** `5.1.6` application with **Ruby** `2.5`.

I ran into the error below when I tried seeding data using `rails db:seed`:

```
rails aborted!
BCrypt::Errors::InvalidHash: invalid hash
```

**Here's how I solved it**:

The version of **Bcrypt** I was using was `3.1.11`, while the **Devise** version was `4.4.3`

I updated the gems to **Bcrypt** `3.1.16` and **Devise** `4.7.3` which fixed the issue.

**Resources**: [BCrypt::Errors::InvalidHash: invalid hash #4861](https://github.com/heartcombo/devise/issues/4861)

That's all.

**I hope this helps**

Comment: It does help, thanks.

Comment: Bcrypt 3.1.16 and even Devise 4.3.0 did the trick for me.

Comment: work for me. I only updated la gema Bcrypt to 3.1.16. I didn't have to touch devise.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're assuming that the user password is hashed with BCrypt even if it was already converted to Authlogic in the first run. You could check whether `@user.password_digest.present?` and if that is the case, you should probably check the password from the params against that.

Furthermore, when creating the digest for Authlogic, you're taking the already-bcrypted value in `pass` and hashing it again. Instead, when creating the authlogic digest, it only requires the password from the params, too.

Comment: Where will password_digest get set? Whenever I try to access it, it says 'error accessing protected field'. Sorry for the noob questions, but I'm new to ruby. Should password_digest be a field in the 'users' DB table also? What about password_salt?

Comment: u.password_digest.present?
     NoMethodError: protected method `password_digest' called for #
     <User:0x007f822415abf0>